# Organize DRY template for JavaScript experiments?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, sandbox

I'm building a fairly large-scale JavaScript Backbone.js app with this folder organization:

```
app
  index.html

libs
  underscore
  jquery
  [...]

src
  utils
  modules
  [...]
```

The index.html file basically loads up all the Backbone.js Routers etc. and instantiates AMD modules etc.

**Often however, I find the need to create small applications that basically share dependencies with the Big app.**

Suppose I need to create 3 small experiments (separate pages) that all load the same usual suspects (underscore, backbone and a couple of util libraries and modules I've written).

They may though differ in: 1) how they extend these JavaScript libraries, 2) what gets instantiated and 3) markup and interaction.

**How do I keep this experimentation DRY?

How do I set up this "extendable Template"?**

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this is where having a good build system comes in. The more complex your setup, the more useful it is to be able to set up configuration files that can keep your dependency management consolidated in one place. This becomes particularly important when:

- You need to load the same sets of dependencies on multiple static pages, but your dependency lists change often during development.
- You need to be able to easily create compressed versions of the dependencies for a production version. I find this is pretty important with Backbone, because the uncompressed versions are really big but quite useful during development.

I've generally used [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) for this, but there are lot of build systems out there. What I've done in the past is:

1. Set up an `index.tmpl.html` file with the core HTML markup and placeholders for JS scripts, CSS files, and underscore templates.
2. Make a `build.properties` file that defines my dependency lists. You can group them in different ways under different property names, e.g. `lib.scripts.all` or `util.scripts.all`.
3. In my build process, create a new `index.html` file, based on `index.tmpl.html`, with `<script>` and other tags to load my dependencies. I have different targets to load the raw files or to compress everything into a production-ready single script file.

You can see an example of this setup in [this Github project](https://github.com/nrabinowitz/gapvis).

If I understand your requirements, you could set up a similar build file with a few tweaks to allow you to set a) the HTML template to use (your default index or another with experiment-specific markup), b) the output file, c) the specific sets of dependencies to load, d) additional dependencies to load, e.g. experiment-specific modules or initialization scripts. You could set these properties up in a specific target (if you think you'll reuse them a few times) or just specify them on the command line when you invoke `ant`, via the `-D` flag.

This would allow you a great deal of flexibility to re-use different portions of your code, and has the added benefit of making it easier to move an "experiment" into your core production code, just by including it permanently in your build process.